# Testing a bound function in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the create method of my module, I bind a function to a variable.

```
var __ = function() {};

__.create = function() {
  var instance = new __();

  instance.bound = instance.functionToBindTo.bind(instance, 'boundParameter');

  return instance;
}

__.prototype.functionToBindTo = function(paramater1, parameter2) {
  //do stuff
}
```

I now want to be able to test that calling 'bound', will set 'boundParameter' as parameter1.

Typically I would do something like...

```
'ensure parameter1 passed as first parameter' : function(test) {
  var newInstance = ClassToTest.create();

  newInstance.functionToBindTo = function(parameter1) {
    test.equal(parameter1, 'boundParameter');
  };

  newInstance.bound();

  test.done();
}
```

However, since .bind() actually creates a new function, this doesn't work as I can't override it in the test. I know the option is available to roll my own bind2 method and patch that, but I was hoping there was a way to avoid that.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the right way but for your test case above you can override the `functionToBindTo` in the `ClassToTest` prototype object:

```
'ensure parameter1 passed as first parameter' : function(test) {

  ClassToTest.prototype.functionToBindTo = function(parameter1) {
    test.equal(parameter1, 'boundParameter');
  };

  var newInstance = ClassToTest.create();

  newInstance.bound();

  test.done();
}
```